# Setting-up Reverse Proxy Server in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2

Just had a go at setting up my first Reverse Proxy Server in Apache as follows:

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerName www.domain.org.uk
         ServerAlias domain
         ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domain-error_log
         TransferLog /var/log/httpd/domain-access_log
         ProxyPass / http://domain.org.uk:80/
         ProxyPassReverse / http://domain.org.uk:80/
    </VirtualHost>

but this fails with:

    XCache requires Zend Engine API version 220060519.
    The Zend Engine API version 220090626 which is installed, is newer.
    Contact mOo at http://xcache.lighttpd.net for a later version of XCache.

    Cannot load Zend Extension Manager - it was built with configuration 1.2.0, whereas running engine is API220090626,NTS
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: uploadprogress: Unable to initialize module
    Module compiled with module API=20060613
    PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
    These options need to match
     in Unknown on line 0
    XCache requires Zend Engine API version 220060519.
    The Zend Engine API version 220090626 which is installed, is newer.
    Contact mOo at http://xcache.lighttpd.net for a later version of XCache.

Is it something I have done wrong in the configuration?

Edit:
Spaces now removed as per Chris's suggestion.  Apache now starts up ok but reverse proxy doesn't seem to work.  Server can ping domain.org.uk but no page gets returned.  Also nothing shows in the ErrorLog or TransferLog.

Edit2:
Have changed the config a bit but still nothing working, any suggestions?
/etc/hosts

    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx <domain>.org.uk

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName www.domain.org.uk
    ServerAlias domain
    ProxyHTMLLogVerbose On
    LogLevel Info
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domain-error_log
    TransferLog /var/log/httpd/domain-access_log
    <Location />
      ProxyPass http://domain.org.uk/
      ProxyPassReverse http://domain.org.uk/
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Location>
  </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The error message is about PHP, not Apache.

Comment: btw you have a space between `http://` and `domain.org.uk`

Comment: This is not a reverse proxy configuration problem, it's a build issue. XCache has to be rebuilt against the new PHP version.

Comment: > btw you have a space between http:// and domain.org.uk - that was the answer, thanks Chris.  Took those spaces out and Apache stats fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of xcache and then follow its build instructions.  Check out http://xcache.lighttpd.net/wiki/InstallFromSource, though note that since your php.ini may already have some xcache lines in it, if you follow all those instructions, check the end of your php.ini for duplicate xcache lines.